# Ways to tell interviewers you want some time to think about your decision (Employment in Academia)

Tags: job, interview

I am interviewing for employment in academic labs as a computer scientist, one of which a childhood friend is in and has some position of seniority. According to my friend who has spoken with the PI on the spot, the PI loves my letters of recommendation, my CV, my cover letter, etc. and the PI is willing to offer me the position on the spot if I don't screw up the interview. However, I am still wishing to keep my options open as there are other labs who have given me interviews during the same week as my interview with this current lab. How do I politely tell the PI I want some time to think about it? There are other factors that I want to weigh in like money, relative interest in the projects, my perceived contribution/role, etc.

Comment: *Thank you for the offer, when do you need a decision by?*

Answer (score 6):

Usually, no one expects you to respond to an offer on the spot.

An important distinction to make is that the PI may offer you a *verbal* offer on the spot but generally it takes some time to get the *formal* offer. Accepting the verbal offer does not necessarily mean you have the job.

If the PI gives you a verbal offer, then just respond with a compliment (e.g., "Thank you, I am very impressed with your lab") and then ask when to expect the formal offer and when you should respond by.

Answer (score -1):

In Academia (for TT positions), usually the Chair or head of search committee will send you the offer letter with 1-3 weeks to respond to the offer. However, if you know that you are not going to take the position, its better to respond right away so not to waste the search committee time.

Comment: While this might be true for some TT jobs in some departments in some countries (definitely not in the UK for any departments), this sounds very formal for hiring an what sounds like an RA.

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing that out! I will edit my post.